# Image isn't rotating within canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, interaction

I've searched through stackoverflow and found some code that would help with rotating an image, but it's not working. I don't see any errors, and it's getting the radians and degrees, so things should work, but the image within the canvas doesn't rotate.

The code should start rotating the image when the user clicks on the canvas and then moves the mouse. When they release the mouse on the page, or on the canvas, it should stop the rotation of the image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var mouseDown = false;
    var intID;
    var mouse_x = 0;
    var mouse_y = 0;        
    var canvas;            
    var img;

    function init()
    {
        canvas = document.getElementById("wheelCanvas");
        img = new Image();
        img.src = 'images/wheel.png';

        img.onload = function() {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");        

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        }

        canvas.onmousedown = function(event)
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            intID = setInterval(rotateWheel, 100);                
        }

        canvas.onmouseup = function(event)
        {
            mouseDown = false;
            clearInterval(intID);
        }

        canvas.onmousemove = function(event)
        {
            if(mouseDown)
            {
                mouse_x = event.pageX;
                mouse_y = event.pageY;
            }
        }

        document.onmouseup = function(event)
        {
            mouseDown = false;
            clearInterval(intID);
        }
    }

    function rotateWheel()
    {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 

        var center_x = canvas.width / 2;
        var center_y = canvas.height / 2;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = Math.round((radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180);

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(425,425);
        ctx.rotate(degree*(Math.Pi/180));
        ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width/2, -img.height/2);
        ctx.restore();
        console.log(degree);

        if(!mouseDown) { clearInterval(intID); }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Always better to create a code snippet, so the issue can be better analyzed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typed "Math.Pi" instead of "Math.PI" on the line

```
    ctx.rotate(degree*(Math.Pi/180));
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezvj9rns/